# Is there a way to disable mysql enterprise audit for a particular mysqldump/restore session

Tags: mysql, audit

I am using mysql enterprise audit in our production, which is working perfectly fine. I have filter rule applied such that all table access queries are logged.
However while dumping or restoring a large table, audit log gets bloated with selects/inserts commands from the dump. Can I disable the audit for that particular dump/restore session ? I am on mysql enterprise server 8.0.32.

I cannot use **set global audit_log_disable=1;** as it would disable audit log for all sessions. Also, I cannot exclude this account from logging, as someone may misuse this account for inserts(without being caught ofcourse :D)